# trouble with performing coordinate map/interpolation with interp2d

Tags: python, scipy

I have what is essentially a 4 column lookup table:  cols 1, 2 are the respective xi,yj coordinates which map to x'i, y'j coordinates in the respective 3rd and 4th cols.

My goal is to provide a method to enter some (xnew,ynew) position within the range of my look-up values in the 1st and 2nd columns(xi,yj) then map that position to an interpolated (x'i,y'j) from the range of positions in the 3rd and 4th cols of the lut.

I have tried using interp2d, but have not been able to figure out how to enter the arrays into the proper format.  For example: I don't understand why `scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x'i, y'j, [xi,yj] kind='linear')` gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid'.
```

This seems so simple, but I have not been able to figure it out. I will gladly provide more information if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interp2d` requires that the interpolated function be 1D, see [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html):

> **z** : 1-D ndarray The values of the function to interpolate at the data
>   points. If z is a multi-dimensional array, it is flattened before use.

So when you enter `[xi,yj]`, it gets converted from its `(2, n)` shape to `(2*n,)`, hence the error.

You can get around this setting up two different interpolating functions, one for each coordinate. If your lut is a single array of shape `(n, 4)`, you would do something like:

```
x_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(lut[0], lut[1], lut[2], kind = 'linear')
y_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(lut[0], lut[1], lut[3], kind = 'linear')
```

And you can now do things like:

```
new_x, new_y = x_interp(x, y), y_interp(x, y)
```